# how to group by columns id and manager_id without using aggregate functions

Tags: mysql

how to group by columns id and manager_id without using aggregate functions.
Below is the sample data. I want to group by id and manager_id and order by created_date desc.

```
   id       manager_id    manager_mail                                     created_date  
------        ----------  --------------------------------------    ---------------------
  1765        2182  Sumana.n@test.com         2016-08-16 11:35:31
  1765        2182  Sumana.n@test.com         2016-08-16 11:35:32
  1765        2182  Sumana.n@test.com         2016-07-05 14:01:15
  1765        2182  Sumana.n@test.com         2016-07-05 14:00:22
  1765        2182  Sumana.n@test.com         2016-07-05 13:59:12
  1765        2182  Sumana.n@test.com         2016-07-05 13:58:13
  1765        2182  Sumana.n@test.com         2016-06-09 08:34:55
  1765        2652  Abhijit.s@test.com        2016-04-22 01:37:39
  1765        2652  Abhijit.s@test.com        2016-02-02 23:00:00
  1765        2652  Abhijit.s@test.com        2016-01-31 23:00:00
  1765        2652  Abhijit.s@test.com        2016-01-30 23:00:00
  1765        2652  Abhijit.s@test.com        2016-01-29 23:00:00
  1765        2652  Abhijit.s@test.com        2016-01-28 23:00:00
  1765        2652  Abhijit.s@test.com        2016-01-27 23:00:00
  1765        2652  Abhijit.s@test.com        2016-01-26 23:00:00
  1765        2652  Abhijit.s@test.com        2016-01-25 23:00:00
  1765        2652  Abhijit.s@test.com        2016-01-24 23:00:00
  1765        2652  Abhijit.s@test.com        2016-01-23 23:00:00
  1765        2652  Abhijit.s@test.com        2016-01-22 23:00:00
  1765        2652  Abhijit.s@test.com        2016-01-21 23:00:00
  1765        2652  Abhijit.s@test.com        2016-01-20 23:00:00
  1765        2652  Abhijit.s@test.com        2016-01-08 23:00:00
  1765        2652  Abhijit.s@test.com        2015-12-15 11:51:57
  1765        1702  KARTHIK.r@test.COM        2015-12-15 11:51:57
```

Comment: Can you show us the output you expect, or rather a small snapshot of that output?  One interpretation of your question is that all you need is an `ORDER BY` clause.  This seems trivial, but seeing your output would clarify this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative to using aggregation here would be to use a subquery which identifies the latest record for each `id`/`manager_id` pair:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE created_date = (SELECT MAX(created_date) FROM yourTable t2
                      WHERE t1.id = t2.id AND t1.manager_id = t2.manager_id);
```

But in practice I would go with `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT id, manager_id, MAX(created_date) AS max_created_date
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY id, manager_id
) t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id AND
       t1.manager_id = t2.manager_id AND
       t1.created_date = t2.max_created_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach without using aggregate function is use a self (left) join, To get the most latest row based on `created_date` per `id` and `manager_id` you can use following query

```
select a.*
from demo a
left join demo b
on a.id = b.id 
and a.manager_id = b.manager_id 
and a.created_date < b.created_date
where b.id is null
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/ZGQX20924)